# Updating d3.js liquid chart when the current value changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I have a requirement where I need to update the d3 liquid chart when the value changes.

I've created a buildChart function and I need an updateChart function that should get triggered on a prop change. I have some old update code commented at the bottom - but I am unsure how to adapt it to this particular chart.

I want to be able to update the number and adjust the water level without resetting/remaking the chart.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-thompson-rz8nlv

```
import React from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import './LiquidChart1.scss'

class LiquidChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()

    this.state = {
      numberCurrent: this.props.numberCurrent ? this.props.numberCurrent : 0,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('--------------liquid chart')
    console.log(
      'JSON.stringify(nextProps.numberCurrent)',
      JSON.stringify(nextProps.numberCurrent),
    )
    console.log(
      'JSON.stringify(this.state.numberCurrent)',
      JSON.stringify(this.state.numberCurrent),
    )

    // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
    if (
      JSON.stringify(nextProps.numberCurrent) !==
      JSON.stringify(this.state.numberCurrent)
    ) {
      console.log('SET NEW DATA')
      //if (nextProps.data !== this.state.data) {
      this.setState({numberCurrent: nextProps.numberCurrent})
      this.updateChart()
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.buildChart()
  }

  updateChart() {}

  buildChart() {
    console.log('BUILD LIQUID CHART')

    var $this = this.myRef.current

    d3.select($this).selectAll('svg').remove()

    function uuid() {
      var buf = new Uint32Array(4)
      window.crypto.getRandomValues(buf)
      var idx = -1
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (
        c,
      ) {
        idx++
        var r = (buf[idx >> 3] >> ((idx % 8) * 4)) & 15
        var v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8
        return v.toString(16)
      })
    }

    function liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings() {
      return {
        minValue: 0, // The gauge minimum value.
        maxValue: 100, // The gauge maximum value.
        circleThickness: 0.05, // The outer circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
        circleFillGap: 0.05, // The size of the gap between the outer circle and wave circle as a percentage of the outer circles radius.
        circleColor: '#178BCA', // The color of the outer circle.
        waveHeight: 0.05, // The wave height as a percentage of the radius of the wave circle.
        waveCount: 1, // The number of full waves per width of the wave circle.
        waveRiseTime: 1000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for the wave to rise from 0 to it's final height.
        waveAnimateTime: 18000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for a full wave to enter the wave circle.
        waveRise: true, // Control if the wave should rise from 0 to it's full height, or start at it's full height.
        waveHeightScaling: true, // Controls wave size scaling at low and high fill percentages. When true, wave height reaches it's maximum at 50% fill, and minimum at 0% and 100% fill. This helps to prevent the wave from making the wave circle from appear totally full or empty when near it's minimum or maximum fill.
        waveAnimate: true, // Controls if the wave scrolls or is static.
        waveColor: '#178BCA', // The color of the fill wave.
        waveOpacity: 1,
        waveOffset: 0, // The amount to initially offset the wave. 0 = no offset. 1 = offset of one full wave.
        textVertPosition: 0.5, // The height at which to display the percentage text withing the wave circle. 0 = bottom, 1 = top.
        textSize: 1, // The relative height of the text to display in the wave circle. 1 = 50%
        valueCountUp: true, // If true, the displayed value counts up from 0 to it's final value upon loading. If false, the final value is displayed.
        displayPercent: true, // If true, a % symbol is displayed after the value.
        textColor: '#045681', // The color of the value text when the wave does not overlap it.
        waveTextColor: '#A4DBf8', // The color of the value text when the wave overlaps it.
      }
    }

    //const dataInput = this.props.data;

    const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
      height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
      radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
      numberCurrent = parseInt(this.props.numberCurrent, 10),
      numberMax = parseInt(this.props.numberMax, 10)

    console.log('numberCurrent', numberCurrent)

    var options = {
      displayPercent: this.props.displayPercent,
      displayText: this.props.displayText,
      circleColor: this.props.circleColor,
      textColor: this.props.textColor,
      waveTextColor: this.props.waveTextColor,
      waveColor: this.props.waveColor,
      waveOpacity: this.props.waveOpacity,
      circleThickness: this.props.circleThickness,
      circleBorderColor: this.props.circleBorderColor,
      textVertPosition: this.props.textVertPosition,
      textHorzPosition: this.props.textHorzPosition,
      waveAnimateTime: this.props.waveAnimateTime,
      chartPaddingLeft: this.props.chartPaddingLeft,
      waveHeightScaling: this.props.waveHeightScaling,
      circleBorderThickness: this.props.circleBorderThickness,
    }

    /*
          const width = 200,
            height = 200,
            radius = 80,
            numberCurrent = 20,
            numberMax = 100;

            var options = {
              "displayPercent": false,
              "displayText": true,
              "circleColor": "grey",
              "textColor": "black" ,
              "waveTextColor":"black",
              "waveColor":"gold" ,
              "waveOpacity":0.5,
              "circleThickness":0,
              "textVertPosition":1,
              "textHorzPosition":20,
              "waveAnimateTime":1000,
              "chartPaddingLeft": 0, 
              "waveHeightScaling": false, 
              "circleBorderThickness": 7, 
            }
      */

    var defaults = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings()
    var config = Object.assign(defaults, options)

    var svg = d3
      .select($this)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'liquidchart')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')

    var liquid = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'liquid')

    var base = liquid.append('g').attr('class', 'base')

    //var circle =
    base
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', 0)
      .attr('cy', 0)
      .attr('r', radius)
      .attr('fill', config.circleColor)
      .style('stroke', config.circleBorderColor)
      .attr('stroke-width', config.circleBorderThickness)

    var value = (numberCurrent / numberMax) * 100

    var textValue = numberCurrent

    if (config.displayPercent) {
      textValue = (numberCurrent / numberMax) * 100
    }

    let elementId = uuid()

    var gauge = liquid.append('g').attr('class', 'gauge')

    //var locationX = parseInt(gauge.style("width"))/2 - radius;
    //var locationY = parseInt(gauge.style("height"))/2 - radius;

    var locationX = -radius
    var locationY = -radius

    var fillPercent =
      Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value)) /
      config.maxValue

    var waveHeightScale
    if (config.waveHeightScaling) {
      waveHeightScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .range([0, config.waveHeight, 0])
        .domain([0, 50, 100])
    } else {
      waveHeightScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .range([config.waveHeight, config.waveHeight])
        .domain([0, 100])
    }

    var textPixels = (config.textSize * radius) / 2
    var textFinalValue = parseFloat(textValue).toFixed(2)
    var textStartValue = config.valueCountUp ? config.minValue : textFinalValue
    var percentText = config.displayPercent ? '%' : ''
    var circleThickness = config.circleThickness * radius
    var circleFillGap = config.circleFillGap * radius
    var fillCircleMargin = circleThickness + circleFillGap
    var fillCircleRadius = radius - fillCircleMargin
    var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius * waveHeightScale(fillPercent * 100)

    var waveLength = (fillCircleRadius * 2) / config.waveCount
    var waveClipCount = 1 + config.waveCount
    var waveClipWidth = waveLength * waveClipCount

    // Rounding functions so that the correct number of decimal places is always displayed as the value counts up.
    var textRounder = function (value) {
      return Math.round(value)
    }

    if (
      parseFloat(textFinalValue) !== parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))
    ) {
      textRounder = function (value) {
        return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1)
      }
    }

    if (
      parseFloat(textFinalValue) !== parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))
    ) {
      textRounder = function (value) {
        return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
      }
    }

    // Data for building the clip wave area.
    var data = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= 40 * waveClipCount; i++) {
      data.push({x: i / (40 * waveClipCount), y: i / 40})
    }

    // Scales for drawing the outer circle.
    var gaugeCircleX = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
      .domain([0, 1])
    var gaugeCircleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, radius])

    // Scales for controlling the size of the clipping path.
    var waveScaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, waveClipWidth]).domain([0, 1])
    var waveScaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, waveHeight]).domain([0, 1])

    // Scales for controlling the position of the clipping path.
    var waveRiseScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
      // such that the it will overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
      // circle at 100%.
      .range([
        fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight,
        fillCircleMargin - waveHeight,
      ])
      .domain([0, 1])

    var waveAnimateScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([0, waveClipWidth - fillCircleRadius * 2]) // Push the clip area one full wave then snap back.
      .domain([0, 1])

    // Scale for controlling the position of the text within the gauge.
    var textRiseScaleY = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([
        fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2,
        fillCircleMargin + textPixels * 0.7,
      ])
      .domain([0, 1])

    // Center the gauge within the parent SVG.
    var gaugeGroup = gauge
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationX + ',' + locationY + ')')

    // Draw the outer circle.
    var gaugeCircleArc = d3
      .arc()
      .startAngle(gaugeCircleX(0))
      .endAngle(gaugeCircleX(1))
      .outerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius))
      .innerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius - circleThickness))

    gaugeGroup
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', gaugeCircleArc)
      .style('fill', config.circleColor)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')')

    var textLeftPlacement = parseInt(radius + config.textHorzPosition, 10)

    //console.log("textStartValue", textStartValue);

    if (config.displayText) {
      // Text where the wave does not overlap.
      var text1 = gaugeGroup
        .append('text')
        .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
        .attr('class', 'liquidFillGaugeText')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', textPixels + 'px')
        .style('fill', config.textColor)
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' +
            textLeftPlacement +
            ',' +
            textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition) +
            ')',
        )
    }

    // The clipping wave area.
    var clipArea = d3
      .area()
      .x(function (d) {
        return waveScaleX(d.x)
      })
      .y0(function (d) {
        return waveScaleY(
          Math.sin(
            Math.PI * 2 * config.waveOffset * -1 +
              Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.waveCount) +
              d.y * 2 * Math.PI,
          ),
        )
      })
      .y1(function (d) {
        return fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight
      })

    var waveGroup = gaugeGroup
      .append('defs')
      .append('clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clipWave' + elementId)

    var wave = waveGroup
      .append('path')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d', clipArea)
      .attr('T', 0)

    // The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
    var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup
      .append('g')
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipWave' + elementId + ')')

    fillCircleGroup
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', radius)
      .attr('cy', radius)
      .attr('r', fillCircleRadius)
      .style('fill', config.waveColor)
      .style('opacity', config.waveOpacity)

    if (config.displayText) {
      // Text where the wave does overlap.
      var text2 = fillCircleGroup
        .append('text')
        .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
        .attr('class', 'liquidFillGaugeText')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', textPixels + 'px')
        .style('fill', config.waveTextColor)
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' +
            textLeftPlacement +
            ',' +
            textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition) +
            ')',
        )
    }

    //let textContent = textStartValue;
    let textInterpolatorValue = textStartValue

    // Make the value count up.
    if (config.valueCountUp) {
      var textTween = function () {
        const i = d3.interpolateNumber(textInterpolatorValue, textFinalValue)
        return function (t) {
          textInterpolatorValue = textRounder(i(t))
          // Set the gauge's text with the new value and append the % sign
          // to the end
          text1.text(textInterpolatorValue + percentText)
          text2.text(textInterpolatorValue + percentText)
        }
      }
      if (config.displayText) {
        text1
          .transition()
          .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
          .tween('text', textTween)

        text2
          .transition()
          .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
          .tween('text', textTween)
      }
    }

    // Make the wave rise. wave and waveGroup are separate so that horizontal and vertical movement can be controlled independently.
    var waveGroupXPosition =
      fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 - waveClipWidth
    if (config.waveRise) {
      waveGroup
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(0) + ')',
        )
        .transition()
        .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' +
            waveGroupXPosition +
            ',' +
            waveRiseScale(fillPercent) +
            ')',
        )
      //.each("start", function(){ wave.attr('transform','translate(1,0)'); }); // This transform is necessary to get the clip wave positioned correctly when waveRise=true and waveAnimate=false. The wave will not position correctly without this, but it's not clear why this is actually necessary.
    } else {
      waveGroup.attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' +
          waveGroupXPosition +
          ',' +
          waveRiseScale(fillPercent) +
          ')',
      )
    }

    if (config.waveAnimate) {
      animateWave()
    }

    function animateWave() {
      wave.attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(wave.attr('T')) + ',0)',
      )
      wave
        .transition()
        .duration(config.waveAnimateTime * (1 - wave.attr('T')))
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(1) + ',0)')
        .attr('T', 1)
        .on('end', function () {
          wave.attr('T', 0)
          animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime)
        })
    }

    /*
      function GaugeUpdater(){
        this.update = function(value){
          var newFinalValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
          var textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return Math.round(value); };
          if(parseFloat(newFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounderUpdater(newFinalValue))){
              textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1); };
          }
          if(parseFloat(newFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounderUpdater(newFinalValue))){
              textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2); };
          }

          let textContent = textStartValue; 

          var textTween = function(){
               var i = d3.interpolate(textContent, parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
               return function(t) { textContent = textRounderUpdater(i(t)) + percentText; }
          };

          text1.transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .tween("text", textTween);
          
          text2.transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .tween("text", textTween);

          var fillPercent = Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value))/config.maxValue;
          var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius*waveHeightScale(fillPercent*100);
          var waveRiseScale = d3.scaleLinear()
              // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
              // such that the it will overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
              // circle at 100%.
              .range([(fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2+waveHeight),(fillCircleMargin-waveHeight)])
              .domain([0,1]);

          var newHeight = waveRiseScale(fillPercent);
          var waveScaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,waveClipWidth]).domain([0,1]);
          var waveScaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,waveHeight]).domain([0,1]);
          var newClipArea;
          
          if(config.waveHeightScaling){
              newClipArea = d3.area()
                .x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); } )
                .y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d.y*2*Math.PI));} )
                .y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius*2 + waveHeight); } );
          } else {
              newClipArea = clipArea;
          }

          var newWavePosition = config.waveAnimate?waveAnimateScale(1):0;
          wave.transition()
              .duration(0)
              .transition()
              .duration(config.waveAnimate?(config.waveAnimateTime * (1-wave.attr('T'))):(config.waveRiseTime))
              .ease('linear')
              .attr('d', newClipArea)
              .attr('transform','translate('+newWavePosition+',0)')
              .attr('T','1')
              .each("end", function(){
                  if(config.waveAnimate){
                      wave.attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(0)+',0)');
                      animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime);
                  }
              });
          waveGroup.transition()
              .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
              .attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+newHeight+')')
        }
      }

      return new GaugeUpdater();
      */
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} className="LiquidChart" />
  }
}
export default LiquidChart
```

usage

```
  <LiquidChart
    data={[{label: '', value: 50}]}
    width="70"
    height="70"
    r="25"
    numberCurrent={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
    numberMax={100}
    displayPercent={false}
    displayText={true}
    circleColor="grey"
    textColor="black"
    waveTextColor="black"
    waveColor="#f3f2ef"
    waveOpacity={0.5}
    circleThickness={0}
    textVertPosition={0.5}
    textHorzPosition={0}
    waveAnimateTime={1000}
    chartPaddingLeft={0}
    waveHeightScaling={false}
    circleBorderColor="#ef7e60"
    circleBorderThickness={5}
  />
```